# What does TO_DATE('235959', 'HH24MISS') mean?

Tags: sql, oracle

I came across a SQL query with below conditional clause

```
To_Char(CRTE_TMS, 'YYYYmmddHH24MISS')  between To_Char (TO_DATE(:endDtTime,'YYYYmmddHH24MISS')-TO_DATE('235959', 'HH24MISS')) and  :endDtTime
```

My high level understanding is that create time stamp should be between some time before end time and end time.
Not sure what does TO_DATE('235959', 'HH24MISS') mean.

If I run the below query on 5th Feb it returns 1st Feb

```
SELECT TO_DATE('235959', 'HH24MISS') FROM DUAl
```

Please help me understand what exactly this condition mean.

Comment: `TO_DATE` function called without a date component defaults to start of current month.

Comment: This condition is wrong, wrong, wrong. Timestamps should not (can not!) be compared by converting them to strings (TO_CHAR). Instead of trying to understand it, you should simply ignore it. Is it in a query you are required to maintain? If so, you would do very well to rewrite it so that you compare timestamps to timestamps, not via string conversion.

Comment: Here's the documentation for the `TO_DATE` function: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TO_DATE('235959', 'HH24MISS')` creates a `DATE` value. Note, in Oracle data type `DATE` always contains date and time part.

If you don't provide any date value then Oracle defaults it to the first day of current months, so `TO_DATE('235959', 'HH24MISS')` returns "2018-02-01  23:59:59"

I don't think this condition makes sense:

```
To_Char(CRTE_TMS, 'YYYYmmddHH24MISS')  
    between To_Char (TO_DATE(:endDtTime,'YYYYmmddHH24MISS')-TO_DATE('235959', 'HH24MISS')) 
       and  :endDtTime
```

First, you should compare `DATE` values, not strings.

I **assume** `TO_DATE(:endDtTime,'YYYYmmddHH24MISS')-TO_DATE('235959', 'HH24MISS'))` is wrong. I think you mean `TO_DATE(:endDtTime,'YYYYmmddHH24MISS') - 1 + (1/24/60/60)`

This will subtract 1 day plus 1 Second (1/24/60/60), i.e. subtract 23:59:59.
Another possibility would be `TO_DATE(:endDtTime,'YYYYmmddHH24MISS') - INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND`.

So, your condition could be

```
WHERE CRTE_TMS between TO_DATE(:endDtTime,'YYYYmmddHH24MISS') - 1 + (1/24/60/60) AND :endDtTime
```

Answer (score 1):

This could probably be a comment instead of an answer.. Sorry do not have enough reputation.

HH24 is the 24 hour format of the hours.
235959 is 23 hours 59 minutes 59 second.

In a 12 hour format it means 11:59:59 PM.

The thing you are trying to do is converting date format into character and comparing it with other dates by converting them to character format using To_char. I do not suggest that.
The below would give the first of the month

```
SELECT TO_DATE('235959', 'HH24MISS') FROM DUAl;
```

I am not able to understand what you are trying to achieve here.
The below syntax gives in the character format which is the difference between two dates. for example 4 days and 10 hours.

```
To_Char (TO_DATE(:endDtTime,'YYYYmmddHH24MISS')-TO_DATE('235959', 'HH24MISS'))
```

and then you are trying to do a comparision like date between (4 days and 10 hours) and :endtime. This is incorrect.

You could use the below to convert to date format.

```
to_date('01012018 23:59:59','MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS')

select case when to_date('01012018 23:59:59','MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS') between :begindate and :enddate then 1
else null
from dual;
```